# How can I generate the serial no with nested field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I generate the player position when I click on add player?
I am using Ruby 1.9.3 rails 3.2.9 and Nested form. 
my code is:

```
    <%= f.fields_for :event_players, :validate=>true do |player| %>
  position : <%= player.text_field :position,:placeholder=>"Pos" %>
  player name <%= player.text_field :name ,  :class => 'search_player_live_result-new',:placeholder=>"Player",:validate=>true%>
<%end%>
 <%= f.link_to_add "add player", :event_players, :class=>"icon-plus no_of_places",:style=>"font-size: 14px;", :data => { :target => "#pokerResultPlayers" } %>
```

Comment: @Pavan I changed that to ruby for him :)

Comment: @Pavan  i am using rails 3.2.9..

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
<%= f.fields_for :event_players, :validate=>true do |player| %>
  serial number: <%= player.options[:child_index] %>
  position : <%= player.text_field :position, :placeholder => "Pos" %>
  player name <%= player.text_field :name, :class => 'search_player_live_result-new', :placeholder => "Player", :validate => true %>
<% end %>
```